# How to copy file recursively into all folders with a specific name (batch file would be preferred)

Tags: file, batch-file, recursion, copy, directory

What I am trying to do is to copy a **NOMEDIA** file into all of the sub-folders named *EXTRAS* as well as all of their sub-folders but no other folders than those.

For example, these are where the **NOMEDIA** files should(n't) be copied:

```
**FALSE** ===>  F:\Movies\1234\  
**TRUE** ====>  F:\Movies\1234\Extras\  
**TRUE** ====>  F:\Movies\1234\Extras\1\  
**TRUE** ====>  F:\Movies\1234\Extras\2\  
**FALSE** ===>  F:\Movies\5678\  
**TRUE** ====>  F:\Movies\5678\Extras\
```

This code will copy the **NOMEDIA** file into the *EXTRAS* folder only but none of their sub-folders and will also create a new file called "Extras" in all directories and sub-directories:

```
for /r "DRIVE:PATH" %i in (Extras.) do @copy "DRIVE:PATH\.nomedia" "%i"
```

And this copies the **NOMEDIA** file in to all directories and subdirectories.

```
for /r "DRIVE:PATH" %i in (.) do @copy "DRIVE:PATH\.nomedia" "%i"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

EDIT:

This is the code that worked from `@Magoo's` solution:

```
for /r "DRIVE:PATH" %i in (.) do echo "%i"|find /i "\extras\" >nul&if not errorlevel 1 copy "DRIVE:PATH\.nomedia" "%i"
```

Thank you also `@Aacini` and `@aschipfl` for your help as well! :-)

Comment: `for /F "delims=" %i in ('dir /S /B /A:D "DRIVE:PATH" ^| findstr "\\Extras\\"') do @copy "DRIVE:PATH\.nomedia" "%i"`

Comment: In batch files, replace `%i` by `%%i`!

Comment: @Aacini that works, except for one thing: it doesn't copy the file into the actual _Extras_ folder, only it's subfolders. How do I get it to also copy there?  Thank you!

Comment: Change `findstr "\\Extras\\"` by `findstr "\\Extras"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.... do echo "%i"|find /i "\extras\" >nul&if not errorlevel 1 copy....
```

This echoes each pathname found into `find` which attempts to locate the string `\extras\` in `/i` case-insensitive mode. The output of `find` is suppressed by the `>nul`. `find` will set `errorlevel` to `0` if the string was found, `1` otherwise, so you can then use the original `if errorlevel` syntax (where "if errorlevel *n*" will be true if `errorlevel` is *n* **or greater than *n***) and negate it with a *not* to detect errorlevel = 0 (ie. string found).

Comment: Thank you very much, @Magoo! This did the trick! Took a few minutes to get it to work right, I'm not very good at this kind of stuff... I'm going to post the full code that worked in the above post for future viewers. Thanks again!